# rails gem incompatibility clearance & railties, what should I do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, clearance, railtie

I have rails 3.017, and clearance 1.0.0.rc2 and trying to install gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.1'

Do I need an older version of jquery-rails? If so, how can I figure this out?

thanks
Joel

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
 In Gemfile:
  jquery-rails (~> 2.1) ruby depends on
    railties (< 5.0, >= 3.1.0) ruby

  clearance (= 1.0.0.rc2) ruby depends on
    railties (3.0.17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need an older version of this gem. If you don't specify a certain version of `jquery-rails` in your `Gemfile`, `Bundler` will find the matching version for you, if you run `bundle install`.

You can find out the dependencies of a gem with the gem manager:

```
$ gem dependency jquery-rails -v 2.1.3
```